# Why a 300*300 Oval cannot fit a 300*300 Canvas perfectly?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *


class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.ball = canvas.create_oval(self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2, fill="red")

# initialize root Window and canvas
root = Tk()
root.title("Balls")
root.resizable(False, False)
canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()

# create ball objects
ball = Ball(canvas, 0, 0, 300, 300)
root.mainloop()
```

As you see, I draw a 300*300 Oval in a 300*300 canvas, but the oval didn't fit the canvas perfectly. The result is(Mac OS):

[image]

So my question is:

1. Why it's not fit perfectly?
2. What should I do to avoid such awkward things?

---

EDIT:

`ball = Ball(canvas, 1, 1, 299, 299)` doesn't work either, it gives:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that coordinate (0,0) is actually underneath the window decorator of the OS. Windows has the same problem. The only "solution" is to draw at an offset.

Comment: @cricket_007: it's not under the "window decorator", it's simply under its own border.

Comment: On Windows 10 with 3.5.1 (tk 8.6.4), `Ball(canvas, 2, 2, 301, 301)` works great.  I added `bg='blue'` to the Canvas call and a magnifier to check carefully.  Also see comment on Oakley's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drawable area of the canvas is by default less than the total width and height of the canvas. The total size includes the widget border and the highlight ring. If you want the drawable area to be 100% of the width and height then you need to set both the `borderwidth` and `highlightthickness` attributes of the canvas to 0 (zero).

Comment: After these changes, 0,0,300,300 (on 'blue' canvas) worked great -- four edges all same.

Comment: Follow your advice to create canvas by `canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)`. It works. Really thanks!